# Return list based on has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A State can have many Units. A Unit can only have one State.

On the home page I want to return a list of ONLY the states that actually have units. Right now they are all listed by their name.

So if Arizona and Colorado are the only ones with units...they will only show up on the home page.

I'm new to Rails and I've searched and searched. But, I'm missing something. Seems like it would be some sort of query or filter on the controller? So it is only returning the States that have Units? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Static page controller

  def home
   @units = Unit.all
   @states = State.order('long_name')
  end



Home view

<% @states.each do |state| %>
<%= link_to state.long_name, state %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN should be enough:

```
@states = State.joins(:units).order('states.long_name ASC')
```

or, you can move this to model scopes:

```
scope :with_units, joins(:units).order('states.long_name ASC')
```

and call it in controller with:

```
@states = State.with_units
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller is not a place for that. It is a typical model concern. This should get you working:

```
States.all.select {|state| !state.units.empty?}
```

However it would be much nicer to create the following method for State class:

```
class State <ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def class.with_units
    select {|state| !state.units.empty?}
  end
end
```

This will give you:

```
State.with_units     #=> All states with units
```

But can also be used on association:

```
user.favourite_states.with_units      #=> All user's favourite states filtered to ones with units.
```

Comment: While the advice to move this logic to the model is good, you really out to do the filtering in active record rather than with `Array#select`. That'll let you chain other query methods onto it, probably be faster, etc. `joins` is the right tool for that; something like: `State.joins(:units).group('states.id')`

Comment: I understand this better now, thank you. Is the scope that @Mareklipka mentioned the same thing? Seems easier.

Comment: Yes it does exactly some thing and indeed using joins is much better idea. :)

Comment: @Longcreative: The scope approach is in fact more effective as it uses database query to filter results. You may only need to use `group('states.id'), as gregates pointed out.

Comment: WHat I have in mind was that "scope :with_units, blah" is exactely same as def self.with_units blah end". Using join instead of select is much faster and memory friendly, as it doesn't take all the records from db, just the right one (and select approach takes all of them and then reject the wrong one)

Comment: So here is an interesting issue. When I populate the Units, a state that has more than one shows up on the homepage each time. So I have Arizona, Arizona, Arizona... I'm guessing I need to rethink my View? Or is that a Controller thing? Here is my view '<% @states.each do |state| %> <%= link_to state.long_name, state %><% end %>'

Comment: Hm, that makes sense because you joining tables, so states will show up as many times as number of units it has. Add .group('states.id') as suggested by @gregates in first comment.

Comment: Awesome. Worked with @states = State.with_units.group('states.id')